# Linear Transformation from R2 -> R3?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Hi I'm new to Linear Transformation and one of our exercise have this question and I have no idea what to do on this one.

Suppose a transformation from R2 → R3 is represented by

```
                                                  1  0
                                              T = 2  4
                                                  7  3
```

with respect to the basis {(2, 1) , (1, 5)} and the standard basis of R3. What are T (1, 4)
and T (3, 5)?
*I'm new to this website I have absolutely no idea how to write a matrix on it*

I tried but at best what I got is absolutely wrong and no where close to solving it. Any hints or tips to do this one will surely help! thank you so much.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: I  have absolutely no idea what I'm doing.I using T{(1,4),(3,5)} and (1,4) is correspond to the first column [1 2 7] and the second T = (3,5) is correspond to the second column [0 4 3] then T(1,4) = (1, 2, 7) = 1(1,0,0) + 2(0,1,0) + 7(0,0,1) the same apply to the (3,5) and I'm stuck and lost I have no idea what I just did

Comment: Write $(1,4)$ and $(3,5)$ as linear combinations of basis elements.

Comment: so you mean like this?
(1,4) = (1,2,7) = 1(1,0,0) + 2(0,1,0) + 7(0,0,1)  &
(3,5) = (0,4,3) = 4(0,1,0) + 3(0,0,1)

Comment: Find $a,b$ such that $(1,4)=a(2,1)+b(1,5)$ and calculate $T(a,b)$. Do the same thing with $(3,5)$

Comment: I don't get it.